# How to convert json field which starts with number to domain object using spring data?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I'm working with such resource:
https://coinmarketcap-nexuist.rhcloud.com/api/all
 It returns list of cryptocurrencies and current prices in json.

Spring boot is in my stack so for all previous cases it converts json to my domain object well.
 But now i'm experiencing problem because one of currency names starts with a number. As you know it's not possible to use number as first variable letter.

I've googled to find some workaround without any success. Does anybody knows how to handle it?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use a specific library , GSON or JAckson etc?

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Jackson to parse the JSON into Java Objects then you can specify the JSON Property name to parse it. For example:

```
@JsonProperty("404_StartingWithADigit")
String data;
```

The `data` variable will hold whatever value was present in the JSON. More details about [Jackson Annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations).

GSON provides a similar annotation `@SerializedName` which does the same thing. More details are available [here](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html).

Comment: The above answer by @Ashray is correct. Just to clarify a bit:
"404_StartingWithADigit" is the exact name of the field key, not some code that Jackson uses.
"data" is the new name that you're giving to the value that came in with the key of "404_StartingWithADigit"